# Ошибка при запуске Java Web приложения

Tags: java, servlet, tomcat, heroku

Всем привет, есть сайт, при попытке запустить с консоли команду `java -jar target/dependency/webapp-runner.jar --session-store memcache target/*.war`, получаю ошибку. Вот ссылка на [лог](https://github.com/MainStar/Lya-mur.core.2.x/blob/master/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/log) с консоли.

Вот такая структура проекта:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

`web.xml` можно увидеть вот [здесь](https://github.com/MainStar/Lya-mur.core.2.x/blob/master/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml).

Как исправить эту ошибку?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поменяйте мапинг сервлетов с указанием полного пути от корневой папки:

```
<url-pattern>/service-gruming</url-pattern>
```

ну и для других сервлетов также.

---

Чтобы понять каким образом части URL мапятся к сервлету можно почитать [здесь](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/bnaep/index.html) и/или [тут](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19226-01/820-7627/bnaep/index.html).

> Псевдоним идентифицирует веб-компонент, который должен обрабатывать
>   запрос. Путь псевдонимов должен начинаться с косой черты (/) и
>   заканчиваться строкой или подстановочным выражением с расширением
>   (например, * .jsp).